# Resource to learn assembly code

Tags: c++, reference-request, performance, assembly

I'm a PhD student in mechanical engineering and I have to perform a lot of simulations for my project. In my lab we use several well-known libraries, from FEM to machine learning. As we're doing performance critical simulations, I've heard the advisor saying that being able to read assembly code is certainly a very promising way to see what the compiler is doing and hence optimise some relevant parts of a code.

Of course, I will never need to write directly assembly instructions, but during my PhD I think it'd be nice if I can read assembly code with GDB or objdump like other computational scientists in my group are doing every now and then.

So, coming to my question: *is the some good reference to recommend, especially targeted to people that just need to understand it?*

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Bit-Assembly-Programming-Linux/dp/1484921909/

Comment: Thanks for the advice.